# Circuit breaker for Log4j 2

Tags: java, log4j2, elastic-stack, sentry, circuit-breaker

Context: Java web application running in Tomcat, Log4j 2 version 2.5. Logging set up to go to one [Sentry](https://sentry.io) instance using the [Raven connector](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/tree/raven-java-8.x/docs) and one ELK (ElasticSearch + Logstash + Kibana) instance.

Configuration looks like this (anonymized):

```
<configuration>
  <appenders>
    <Raven name="Sentry">
      <dsn>https://foo@bar.baz/1</dsn>
    </Raven>
    <Socket name="Logstash" host="1.2.3.4" port="1234">
      <SerializedLayout />
    </Socket>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="Sentry" level="warn" />
      <appender-ref ref="Logstash" />
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Problem is that if Sentry or ELK starts acting up (long response times, unreachable, ...), the application threads get blocked trying to log and the application effectively dies.

Is there a preferred solution to this problem? Some kind of circuit breaker would be ideal here: after detecting a problem with the remote logging destination Log4j 2 would disable the appender for some time.

We use another appender wrapped in an [`<Async/>` appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender), but as far as I understand that is a good solution to make the logging... well, asynchronous, but not to fix the problem of unresponsive log destination.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Sentry appender itself is by default completely async, so it shouldn't ever back up your logger.

Comment: @Brett can you please clarify which Sentry appender you mean? I am still using the old Raven appender, I know that I should upgrade to Sentry as mentioned here https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/

Comment: even with the legacy `raven-java` client, we have defaulted to an async connection for a very long time. Do you have any evidence that Sentry delays are slowing down your logging? They definitely shouldn't -- that would be a bug. Please make an issue on Github if you have any information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In our system we have a special component called logs-forwarder that collects all the logs by log4j and other systems and forwards them to logstash / splunk etc. what might have you. So that's one valid option.